# How to unblacklist ath9k to make RTL8187L work

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I just had a problem after trying to fix my Realtek RTL8187L to work on my ubuntu 12.04 system. Following some instructions (rather eagerly) I blacklisted ath9k and now neither the realtek nor the qualcomm devices work.
No idea how to undo this blacklisting or even get realtek wifi receiver working again..

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Would you mind adding the instructions you followed? Also please include the output of `history | grep blacklist`.

Comment: RTL8187L has support since many years ago, many years *before* 12.04, and so should be any device supported by the ath9k driver. No need to blacklist any and blacklisting the Atheros one has nothing to do with the Realtek.

Comment: Although it should be possible to get it back on track - the above information is a must -, 12.04 will be out of support in a few months. Is it really worth the troubleshooting? No, not really. Consider backup and a fresh install of 14.04, 16.04 or 16.10. Everything *should* work right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove ath9k from the blacklist with

```
sudo sed -i 's/blacklist ath9k/#blacklist ath9k/' /etc/modprobe.d/*
```

Alternatively you should be able to manually load it with
`sudo modprobe ath9k`